# grabbing data from SAP to BlackBerry

Tags: php, json, blackberry, abap, saprfc

im developing an app in java for BlackBerry, right now im building some RFC's in SAP so i can search some info inside the system to show to the blackberry users.

my first attempt (that actually worked): i made a rfc that was called trough a php file and the php file sends the info through Json to the BlackBerry ( and viceversa, the bberry calls the php file and from here to SAP)

my boss told me that i cant use a middleware to do this, that i had to get the data directly from SAP, but our SAP doesn't have the mobile module

my question is: first, can it be done without the middleware? if the answer is yes, then... what should be the cleanest and better way? (we dont have a mobile module!!!!)

SAP==>MiddleWare==>bberry

or

SAP==>bberry???

Comment: Is SAP internet facing ? Does it support any kind of web services ?

Comment: yes it does but for mobile is another story... you require the mobile module... (and we dont have it)

Comment: So, if it's providing web service, why the need for a mobile module? Just use the web services provided to display the data on the native application.

Comment: the native app cant process the data because Blackberry doesn't reads the SAP web output. Json does!!. thats why i read the data thruog php and then i parse it with Json.Parse() so that way i get a string with all the data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have multiple options:

- generate soap webservices from your RFC Modules
- create a simple BSP application that calls your RFC's and returns json or xml data
- you could create an SICF service that accepts and returns json or xml data

Comment: I agree with this. I would rather go the route of trying to exchange data via web services/HTTP requests than RFC calls through another medium (provided that your WAS has the HTTP service enabled, which I am sure it should). Go to SICF to check.

Answer (score 2):

BSP is your best bet. Either to return the XML or even just run the app as a web page from the BSP (if the use case suits). You will have to hand craft the HTML to get it to work though since the blackberry browser only supports certin features.

Answer (score 1):

We are right now in the process of the SAP Netweaver Gateway RampUp. This fits your requirements because it returns the sap data via restful web services and has proxy generators for several programming languages. I really like it. Maybe you could give it a try.